# SELECT as subset from same table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do something like this so the result is a combination of 2 seperate selects

```
SELECT
order_number,placed_by,placed_when,updated_by,updated_when,
(SELECT SUM(qty_order<>qty_rec) 
 FROM 1_purchase_orders 
 WHERE order_number=order_number AND line_number<>0)
WHERE
supp_number=4 AND line_number=0;
```

Comment: I don't see a question there.

Comment: You also seem to be missing a `FOR`.

Comment: Are you trying to use a inner query ? I don't see a `FROM` clause to the outer `select`.

Comment: Neither you have used the table of the mother query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlated subquery, you used in your query, must return only one scalar value. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.order_number,
  t1.placed_by,
  t1.placed_when,
  t1.updated_by,
  t1.updated_when, 
  (SELECT SUM(t2.qty_order <> t2.qty_rec) 
   FROM 1_purchase_orders t2
   WHERE t2.order_number = t1.order_number AND t2.line_number <> 0 
   ORDER BY qty_order LIMIT 1) 
FROM 1_purchase_orders t1
WHERE t1.supp_number = 4 AND t1.line_number=0;
```

Comment: Mahmoud that is exactly what I need. Thanks superfast reply!